# Trig function integration problem (substitution)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I got this practice problem:

> $$\int^\ 9sin(x) cos^{-3}(x)dx$$

so what I did is substitute u for cos(x), and du=-sin(x)dx

and I then got

> > $$\int^\ -9u^{-3}du$$

which is equal to

> > $$ \frac{9}2u^{-2}+C$$

I then substituted u=cosx back in and got

> > $$ \frac{9}2cos(x)^{-2}+C$$

But it is not right.

I don't see where I went wrong so if anyone can help me that would be great

Comment: @Hugo I see. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: What makes you think that your solution is incorrect? You may want to note that:$$\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=\sec^2(x)$$and $\sec^2(x)$ can also be written as:$$\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$$

Comment: Differentiate $\frac{9}{2} \cos(x)^{-2}+C$ using chain rule... it's easy. All is good.

Comment: Your answer is correct, check by differentiating the result.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs everyone. I thought I made a mistake because when I graphed them the graphs looked different but its just the C throwing me off. Sorry about that and thank you all for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with your answer.**

$$\frac{9\cos^{-2}x}{2}=\frac{9}{2\cos^{2}x}=\frac{9}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{9\sec^2x}{2}$$
which is likely the answer in the book.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\int^\ 9sin(x) cos^{-3}(x)dx=\int^\ 9\tan(x) \sec^{2}(x)dx$$
let $u=\tan(x)$
$du=\sec^2(x)dx$
$$\int^\ 9udu=9u^2/2+C=\frac{9}{2}\tan^2(x)+C=\frac{9}{2}(\sec^2x-1)+C$$
$$=\frac{9}{2}\sec^2 x+(C-\frac{9}{2})=\frac{9}{2}\sec^2 x+K=\frac{9}{2}\cos^{-2} x+K$$
so your answer is correct

Comment: Thanks for the input. That would work, but why is what I did wrong thought?

Comment: @SpongebobSquareroot-pants you did nothing wrong. Your substituion is perfectly fine and the result is good!

Comment: @luka5z I see... thank you.